# Extract the anti-diagonal of a 2D list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to print the diagonal numbers of this matrix so that I get `[5, 9, 13, 17, 21]`.

I've tried changing the variables in the `for` loop.

```
matrix = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
          [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
          [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
          [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]

diagonal = []
last_column = len(matrix[0]) - 1
for row in matrix:
    diagonal.append([row][0][4])

print(diagonal)
```

Instead of getting the diagonal numbers, I get `[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]`.

Comment: `for row in range(0,len(matrix)): print(matrix[row][len(matrix)-1-row])` this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the anti-diagonal, so you can use a simple list comprehension (assuming `matrix` is square).

```
[matrix[i][-(i+1)] for i in range(len(matrix))]
# [5, 9, 13, 17, 21]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [numpy.diagonal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html)

```
import numpy
matrix = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
          [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
          [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
          [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
arr=numpy.array(matrix)
print(numpy.fliplr(arr).diagonal())
```

Outputs:

```
[ 5  9 13 17 21]
```

To get the  diagonal use `print(arr.diagonal())`

Comment: I would only use numpy when the matrix would be very large. In my own programs I've noticed that numpy can be extremely slow compared to other alternatives. Use profiling to determine what is appropriate